# Software to generate photo gallery HTML with download links

Tags: software-recommendation, photos

I have the following requirement: A software that runs on OS X which takes a number of image files and creates a HTML gallery out of them.

It needs to have the following features:

- Caption and description on a main thumbnail page.
- Medium size pages for each image, which is scaled down to like 600×600 pixels. If some IPTC info is shown, that is great, but not a strict requirement.
- Download links to the full resolution image.

FotoStation is able to do exactly this, however it is rather costly for this single use.

Is there any program that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I use Jalbum. It's very practical and has tons of features and skins.
You can find it here : http://jalbum.net/en/

Comment: It is not free but very powerful with many features.

Comment: I played around with it, but I did not find the option to include the full size image. Are you sure that is in there?

Comment: In the setting=>images, you have a possibility to create a link to original images. Now, I'm not sure for the download link (icon)